# How do you get the UTL_FILE.FILE_TYPE as an out parameter

Tags: java, database, testing, plsql

I'm trying to get the file handle from plsq, I'm trying to see if I can test plsql packages
from Java I have this code:

```
Properties props = Utils.readProps("database.properties");
    Connection con = DBManager.getConnection(props.getProperty("url"), props.getProperty("username"), props.getProperty("password"));
    Object file_type = new Object[3];
    STRUCT oracleRecord;
        try {
            //StructDescriptor fileType = StructDescriptor.createDescriptor("UTL_FILE.FILE_TYPE",con);
            CallableStatement stmt = con.prepareCall("{call simple_test.caller(?,?,?)");
            stmt.setObject(1, "/u01/home/oracle/EI/278");
            stmt.setObject(2, "ql_item_test.txt");
            stmt.registerOutParameter(3, OracleTypes.STRUCT, "UTL_FILE.FILE_TYPE");
            stmt.execute();
            oracleRecord = ((OracleCallableStatement)stmt).getSTRUCT(3);
            file_type = oracleRecord.getAttributes();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

And this plsql code:

```
PROCEDURE caller(file_path VARCHAR2,
                                         file_name VARCHAR2,
                                         fp        OUT UTL_FILE.file_type) IS
                maxLineSize INTEGER;
        BEGIN
                maxLineSize := 1024;
                fp          := UTL_FILE.FOPEN(file_path, file_name, 'R', maxLineSize);
        END;
```

But When I ran it I guess this error:

```
java.sql.SQLException: invalid name pattern: UTL_FILE.FILE_TYPE
```

I'm I getting this error because I can't pass/retrieve plsql types?

Comment: Try `SYS.UTL_FILE.FILE_TYPE`.

Comment: I tried SYS.UTL_FILE.FILE_TYPE
But I'm still getting the same error.

Comment: `UTL_FILE.FILE_TYPE` is a PL/SQL record structure used internally by `UTL_FILE`. What are you trying to do? What possible use can your Java program make of this record?

Comment: I'm trying to test some custom PL/SQL packages that have FILE_TYPE out/in parameters. I'm testing this on Java using JUNIT. I was wondering if I could create/retrieve this PL/SQL record, but it seems I cannot.

Answer (score 1):

UTL_FILE.FILE_TYPE is an PL/SQL "Record" and Oracle JDBC does NOT support Records. It does support Objects and certain collections of objects and primitives. See http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/java.112/e16548/oraoor.htm http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/java.112/e16548/oraarr.htm and http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/java.112/e16548/oraoot.htm#i1078761

BTW, I fail to see what on earth you would do with it in Java anyway...